# Job title for a roleplaying event gamemaster in an online RPG?

Tags: mmo, rpg, online

I'm considering creating a position in an online RPG where the responsibilities would mainly involve conceiving roleplaying-oriented events and plotlines and executing on them using developer tools such as the ability to create instances of NPCs/items and the ability to control NPCs.  Examples of events/plotlines might be "ancient god of evil breaks loose from his prison and attacks the realm" or "upcoming marriage between offspring of powerful dynasties has political opponents trying to disrupt it".

What is the best job title for this sort of position?

The first thing that popped into my head was "customer experience associate", but this appears to have an established meaning in retail where it's a way of dressing up "salesperson".  "Game master" positions in MMOs are generally helpdesk positions with no creative duties or authority.  I want to select something that neither exaggerates nor undersells this person's level of responsibility.

Comment: Are you looking to pay this person as much as a CSR/GM, or as much as a full-time designer? That's usually the determining factor in job titles...

Comment: More in the CSR/GM range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to pay them as a GM/CSR, the title needs to reflect that. Community Event Manager.

On the other hand, if you're expecting them to use the developer tools to design new content, you're probably not going to find anyone willing to take that kind of pay for that responsibility (and do a good job of it).

Comment: Right, my expectation would be that they'd be manipulating existing content to create events, not making new base content.  I don't think I'd ever specify this type of job at that level; if they're capable of making new base content that's up to my standards, I want them focused on that, not direct customer interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Something to do with controlling would work, since it shows they are actually doing something.

Perhaps a Quest Controller?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I've come up with since I wrote this question is Dynamic Content Coordinator.

Answer (score 0):

How about Dungeon Master (DM) to borrow from games like D&D here the DM is the one driving the story and inserting interesting events.

Comment: "Dungeon Master" is a trademark (maybe still a registered trademark) of TSR/WotC/Hasbro.

Comment: "More derivative of D&D" is not really a direction I want to go, anyway.

Comment: I didn't knew such a general something was trademarked (two normal words). It did fit the description though.  (I wonder where the -2 came from btw, bit harsh).